# Application Crash Automatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

I am implementing the list view with image and frame layout (Button and LinearLayout) but when i scroll the list many times , the application gets crash automatically...following is my code..
Main.java

```
 public class Main extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
ImageView img, img1;
private AdapterClass adapter;
private String reviewImageLink;

private static final String TAG = "PRANJAL";
private boolean isImage = false;

String fileName[] = new String[10];
private String imgurl;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> searchResult;
private EditText edtSearch;
private Button btnNext;
private ListView list;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);
    edtSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtSearch);
    btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    // list = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.list);
    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    /*
     * JSONObject json = JSONfunctions
     * .getJSONfromURL("http://23.21.228.8/PlutoApp_Beta/consumer_dash/" +
     * "checkIn_confirmation_related_record.php?lat=18.535787&lng=73.891889"
     * );
     */
    JSONObject json = JSONfunctions
            .getJSONfromURL("http://23.21.228.8/PlutoApp_Beta/consumer_dash/checkIn_confirmation_name.php?lat=40.739974&lng=-73.994293&name=shop");

    try {

        JSONArray earthquakes = json.getJSONArray("Display");
        for (int i = 0; i < earthquakes.length(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            JSONObject e = earthquakes.getJSONObject(i);

            map.put("Name", e.getString("name"));
            map.put("Vicinity", e.getString("vicinity"));

            map.put("logo", e.getString("logo"));

            imgurl = e.getString("logo");

            String filename = "a" + i;
            imgurl = e.getString("logo");

            mylist.add(map);
            adapter = new AdapterClass(Main.this,
                    R.layout.my_custom_layout, mylist);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    searchResult = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(mylist);

    // adapter = new AdapterClass(Main.this, R.layout.my_custom_layout,
    // mylist);

    list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    edtSearch.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                edtSearch.clearFocus();
                edtSearch.requestFocus(edtSearch.FOCUS_DOWN);

                String searchText = edtSearch.getText().toString();
                final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mySearchlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                JSONObject json = JSONfunctions
                        .getJSONfromURL("http://23.21.228.8/PlutoApp_Beta/consumer_dash/checkIn_confirmation_name.php?lat=40.739974&lng=-73.994293&name="
                                + searchText);
                try {

                    JSONArray Search = json.getJSONArray("Display");
                    for (int i = 0; i < Search.length(); i++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> mapSearch = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        JSONObject e = Search.getJSONObject(i);
                        String filename = "b" + i;
                        mapSearch.put("Name", e.getString("name"));
                        mapSearch.put("Vicinity", e.getString("vicinity"));

                        mapSearch.put("logo", e.getString("logo"));

                        imgurl = e.getString("logo");

                        imgurl = e.getString("logo");

                        mySearchlist.add(mapSearch);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
                }

                AdapterClass adapter = new AdapterClass(Main.this,
                        R.layout.my_custom_layout, mySearchlist);
                setListAdapter(adapter);

                list.setTextFilterEnabled(true); // list.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            searchResult = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(mylist);

            // adapter = new AdapterClass(Main.this, R.layout.main, mylist);
            adapter = new AdapterClass(Main.this,
                    R.layout.my_custom_layout, mylist);

            list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });

}

}
```

AdapterClass.java

```
public class AdapterClass extends BaseAdapter {

int images[];
Context context;
String string[];
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private int resourceId;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myList;
private View view;
private Animation anim_left_right;
private Animation anim_right_left;
private FrameLayout frame;
private LinearLayout ll;
private int width;
private int height;
private String tag;
private boolean flag;

private boolean firstRun = true;
public int closedPosition;
private boolean flagset = true;
private boolean firstRunTouch;
private boolean flag3 = false;
public boolean ff = true;
private View ll1;
private View ll2;
private boolean flag4 = false;
private int j = 1;
private boolean flag5 = false;
private boolean flag6 = false;
private boolean flag2;
private boolean flag0;
private boolean flag7= true;
private boolean flag8 = true;
private Animation MyAnimation;
public ImageLoader imageLoader;

public AdapterClass(Context context, int resourceId,
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myList) {

    this.context = context;
    this.resourceId = resourceId;
    this.myList = myList;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context.getApplicationContext());
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return myList.size();
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    System.out.println("Getview Method is called");

    HashMap<String, String> map = getItem(position);



    /*if(flag==true){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Inside Flag= true"+position, 1000).show();
        ll2.startAnimation(anim_right_left);
        ll2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(130, height));
        flag=false;
    }*/


    //if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_custom_layout, parent,
                false);

//  }

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    System.out.println("hi");

    ll = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ll1);
    width = ll.getLayoutParams().width;
    height = ll.getLayoutParams().height;

    frame = (FrameLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.frame);

    ll.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener());

    ll.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());

    TextView from_user = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.from_user);

    TextView from_user_id = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.from_user_id);

    Button landed = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    System.out.println("Tag in side getView :" + ll.getTag());

    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "Inside Method startAnimation", 1000).show();
            anim_left_right = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
                    R.anim.anim_left_to_right1);
            anim_right_left = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
                    R.anim.anim_left_to_right2);

            ll.startAnimation(anim_right_left);
            ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(130, height));
            /*AnimationUtils AnimAnimationUtils = null;
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            MyAnimation=AnimAnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ll.getContext(),R.anim.anim_left_to_right1);
            //startAnimation(ll);
            ll.startAnimation(MyAnimation);*/
            return true;
        }


    });

    landed.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Toast.makeText(context,
                    "Button Clicked at position  " + position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    from_user.setText(map.get("Name"));
    from_user_id.setText(map.get("Vicinity"));
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(map.get("logo"), imageView);

    System.out.println("pos" + position + " closedPositon : "
            + closedPosition + " tag : " + ll.getTag());

    String imageUrl = map.get("logo");

    System.out.println("ClosedPosition in getView Method : "
            + closedPosition);
    //if(flag==true){
    //  convertView=null;
    //}
    return convertView;
}

protected void startAnimation(LinearLayout ll3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(context, "Inside Method startAnimation", 1000).show();
    anim_left_right = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
            R.anim.anim_left_to_right1);
    anim_right_left = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
            R.anim.anim_left_to_right2);

    ll3.startAnimation(anim_right_left);
    ll3.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(130, height));

}

@Override
public HashMap<String, String> getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return myList.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;
}

class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    float xstart, xend;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(final View v, MotionEvent event) {
        anim_left_right = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
                R.anim.anim_left_to_right1);
        anim_right_left = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
                R.anim.anim_left_to_right2);
        System.out.println("OnTouch Called..");
        flag = true;
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            xstart = event.getX();
            firstRun = false;
            flag6 = true;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            xend = event.getX();
            if (xend < xstart) {
                flag6 = true;
            }

            if (xstart < xend) {
                System.out.println("inside xstart<xend...");
                flag6 = false;
                flag8=true;
                System.out.println("flag6 : false");
                // if (flag5 == true) {
                // if(flag2==true){
                if (flag4 == true && flag5 == true) { // first time left to

                    flag0 = false;// right is

                    break;
                }
                if(flag7==false){
                    flag8 = false;
                    flag7=true;
                }
                else{
                    flag8=true;
                    //flag6 = true;

                }
                if (flag4 == true && flag0 == true && flag8==true) { // first time left to
                    System.out.println("IF after break is executed.."); // right
                                                                        // is
                    // disabled....
                    System.out.println("first time left to right");
                    System.out.println(" xend :" + xend + ", xstart :"
                            + xstart);
                    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.a);
                    v.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, height));
                    v.startAnimation(anim_left_right);
                    // ll1 = null;
                    flag4 = false;
                    // flag6=false;
                    ff = true;
                }
                // }
                // }

                //ff = true;
            }

            break;

        }
        return false;
    }
}

class MyClickListener implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Animation anim_left_right = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
                R.anim.anim_left_to_right1);
        Animation anim_right_left = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
                R.anim.anim_left_to_right2);
        System.out.println("OnClick Called..");
        // if (flag4 == true || j==1) {
        if (flag6 == true) {
            System.out.println("InSide OnClick..");
            if (ff) {
                System.out.println("InSide OnClick..");
                // closedPosition = (Integer) v.getTag();
                System.out
                        .println("MyTouchListener is Called before getview..");
                System.out.println("closdeposiotion : " + closedPosition);


                v.startAnimation(anim_right_left);
                v.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(130, height));
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                ll1 = v;
                ll2 = v;
                System.out.println("Tag of ll1 in if statement : "
                        + ll1.getTag() + "Tag of ll1 in if statement : "
                        + v.getTag());
                ff = false;
                flag4 = true;
                flag6 = false;
                flag5 = false;
                flag0 = true;
                flag = true;
            } else {
                flag4 = true;
                flag5 = true;
                System.out.println("InSide OnClick..");



                v.startAnimation(anim_right_left);
                v.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(130, height));
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                System.out.println("Tag of ll1 in else statement : "
                        + v.getTag());
                //ll1 = v;
                // flag4 = true;
                flag6 = false;
                // flag5 = true;
                if (ll1 != null) {

                    ll1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.a);
                    ll1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, height));
                    ll1.startAnimation(anim_left_right);
                    System.out.println("Tag of ll1 in else statement : "
                            + ll1.getTag());
                    // ll1 = null;
                    // ff = true;
                    flag5 = false;
                    // flag4 = false;
                    flag7 = false;
                    flag6 = false;
                    flag=true;
                }
                ll1 = v;
                ll2 = v;
            }
        }
    }

    // }

}

}
```

Listpalceholder.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtSearch"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Search"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Clear" />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

<TextView
    android:id="@id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sorry..No Match Found.." 
    android:textSize="20dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My_Custom_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="2dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Landed"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/a"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/from_user"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/from_user_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

please help me....

Comment: Can you post the logcat error?

Answer (score 0):

Issue, is most probably OutOfMemoryError, this question has been answered many times here on SO, please search for outofmemory issue, or image outofmemory issue, or vm budget exceeds, you will get a good set of guidelines.
See this question, to know more about this issue.

[Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object/823966#823966)

Also, unblock the if block, to reuse convertView, it will make proper reuse of the views already being drawn.

```
if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_custom_layout, parent,
                false);

}
```